# SQL Server Filestream - Remote Connection C#

Tags: c#, filestream, sqlfilestream

Is there some way to use SqlFileStream  in a remote connection (out of network, using external ip)?

I know that for use the filestream, i need use Integrated Security = true.
I tried following this article:

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/using-filestream-streaming-io-and-sql-logins-with-impersonation/

But it didnt work for me...
Local (using integrated security), all works fine. But when i try use external ip, i get "Path not found" in SqlFileStream.

I saw this too: [Filestream using SQL Server authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626490/filestream-using-sql-server-authentication)

But i got the same result.

Comment: When you get a sample path, what exactly are you getting? What sort of account are you using?

Comment: Hi. I'm getting: "\\SERVIDOR\MSSQLSERVER\v02-A60EC2F8-2B24-11DF-9CC3-AF2E56D89593\CloudBackup\dbo\BackupFiles\arquivo\7A23DB44-083F-E711-816B-ECF4BBFB859F\VolumeHint-HarddiskVolume4"

Comment: I'm using a SQL user with login.
this my connection string:  Data Source=177.xx.xx.xxxx;Initial Catalog=CloudBackup;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;Connect Timeout=120;

Comment: Well, as it mentioned in the filestream using sql authentication, you would need to impersonate something with permissions.  Impersonating isnt the same as using integrated security...